# Flow: Cannot get this.props.width because property width is missing in T

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, jsx, flowtype

I'm using `Flow` for type check on a `React Native` project.

Reference: https://flow.org/en/docs/types/

I have two files: `SvgRenderer.js` and `Cartoon.js` where:

```
Cartoon extends SvgRenderer
```

Below you have their source code:

**SvgRenderer.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Svg, { G } from 'react-native-svg';

export default class SvgRenderer<T> extends React.Component<T> {

  width: number;
  height: number;
  scaleFactor: number;

  constructor(props: T) {
    super(props);
  }
  ...
  config(originalSize: number[]) {
    switch (true) {
      case (this.props.width != undefined):
        this.scaleFactor = this.props.width / originalSize[0];
        this.width = this.props.width;
        this.height = originalSize[1] * this.scaleFactor;
        break;
      case (this.props.height != undefined):
        this.scaleFactor = this.props.height / originalSize[1];
        this.width = originalSize[0] * this.scaleFactor;
        this.height = this.props.height;
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

**Cartoon.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import SvgRenderer from './SvgRenderer';

type Props = {
  for: string,
  width?: number,
  height?: number,
};

export default class Cartoon extends SvgRenderer<Props> {

  firstBorder: string;

  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return ...
  }
}
```

My problem is that when I run:

```
$ npm run flow
```

I get:

```
Error -------------------- src/helpers/SvgRenderer.js:32:24

Cannot get this.props.width because property width is missing in T [1].

     src/helpers/SvgRenderer.js
     29|     this.originalWidth = originalSize[0];
     30|     this.originalHeight = originalSize[1];
     31|     switch (true) {
     32|       case (this.props.width != undefined):
     33|         this.scaleFactor = this.props.width / this.originalWidth;
     34|         this.width = this.props.width;
     35|         this.height = this.originalHeight * this.scaleFactor;

Error -------------------- src/helpers/SvgRenderer.js:33:39

Cannot get this.props.width because property width is missing in T [1].

     src/helpers/SvgRenderer.js
     30|     this.originalHeight = originalSize[1];
     31|     switch (true) {
     32|       case (this.props.width != undefined):
     33|         this.scaleFactor = this.props.width / this.originalWidth;
     34|         this.width = this.props.width;
     35|         this.height = this.originalHeight * this.scaleFactor;
     36|         break;
```

as you can see on the following image:

[image]

I don't understand why `Flow` says (for `SvgRenderer`):

```
Cannot get this.props.width because property width is missing in T [1].
```

when I actually defined: `width` inside: `Cartoon` as you can see here:

```
type Props = {
  for: string,
  width?: number,
  height?: number,
};
```

I know: `width` and `height` are maybe types but I need them like that.

Any idea on how to adjust the code in order `Flows` considers it is OK?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To allow access `width` and `height` on type `T` flow should be sure `T` actually has this properties. This can be done by defining constraint for generic type parameter:

```
type Dimensions = { width?: number, height?: number };

class SvgRenderer<T: Dimensions> extends React.Component<T> {
  // ...

  config(originalSize: number[]) {
    if (this.props.width != undefined) {
      this.scaleFactor = this.props.width / originalSize[0];
      this.width = this.props.width;
      this.height = originalSize[1] * this.scaleFactor;
      return;
    }

    if (this.props.height != undefined) {
      this.scaleFactor = this.props.height / originalSize[1];
      this.width = originalSize[0] * this.scaleFactor;
      this.height = this.props.height;
    }
  }
}
```

** Also pay attention to slightly changed `config` method (`if` statements used instead of `switch/case`) - this enables flow to refine type of `width/height` (exclude `undefined`) so it will allow you to perform arithmetic operation (`this.props.width / originalSize[0]`). Anyway having `switch (true)` doesn't make much sense.

Try working example [here](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoAlgWwA5wE4AuyYAhgM5gBKApiQMZFR5yZgDketDbA3KqgQCe2amAAiWagDsy6ODLABeMAG8wCdABMCACwD8ALjBSArpgBG1PABowO6ugDmOgoeNnLeMAF8+qOjDkFADKAG6ONFKaVlYAPAAqRhKY0rLyZAB8YNQAHgTSmhQ09AQAdADCLLhS0gQJWSqoYOpaukamFlZ8zfZOLu0eXU1gZHQkMNQAYiX4A514fs106QR4Jgz4ABTYzNhkRvEAlKrDzWQmInjbu2SH3T78S-JQTpv4TuhS48HoAF7Uc08AG0ALrHRrNZroKBgTa6dBkUo7OB7UoabQ6MAAQmUJii1BeNU04NOkPhiNG4ymMy8ynJSJuaNamOAYHejk+3z+1CBAAYQfdIWB6ejdEphToEQyUYjRTpBWTJYjes4iMp2ZyYD9-kCAIwg4j0ykTaYbBak5qcAgmPBSUneUmk6Gw+nI1EqlzY3H4wnUYknIXNI1jE008WuxkeoisjVfLXcvUCi0SqVy8Wxrk6-mGpWlY3Us0KoO5qPh3Nu5UOVUKh3NB0OgTCUQABRu4ohYCgsxGq0+jmswzlbg6ngHPSrLmHgxsqF8-ACQTA5RIhDg8myeQKIXCkWinDwsVbMoawxeeDIBAAQvg90YL3g+4swMsZKt1gQthWjEe9iShedLmuGU7mGWswE4fErj-SErRtKR3BgGB7nrIA)